Understanding an example of resolution of the identity (Schmudgen)
(Spectral Measures and Spectral Integrals chapter, Schmudgen)
Definition $4.1$

A resolution of the identity on a Hilbert space
$\mathcal{H}$ is a one-parameter family $\{E(\lambda) : \lambda \in
 \mathbb{R}\}$ of orthogonal projections on $\mathcal{H}$ such that
[Axiom (i)] $E(\lambda_1) \leq E(\lambda_2) \quad \text{if } \lambda_1
 \leq \lambda_2 \quad (\text{monotonicity}),$
[Axiom (ii)] $\lim_{\lambda \to \lambda_0^+} E(\lambda)x =
 E(\lambda_0)x \quad \text{for } x \in \mathcal{H} \text{ and }
 \lambda_0 \in \mathbb{R} \quad (\text{strong right continuity}),$
[Axiom (iii)] $\lim_{\lambda \to -\infty} E(\lambda)x = 0 \quad
 \text{and} \quad \lim_{\lambda \to +\infty} E(\lambda)x = x \quad
 \text{for } x \in \mathcal{H}.$

Example $4.1$

Let $(\lambda_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a real sequence, and let
$(P_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of orthogonal projections on
$\mathcal{H}$ such that $P_k P_n = 0$ for $k \neq n$ and
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n = I$. (Recall that any infinite sum of pairwise
orthogonal projections converges strongly.) Then $$ E(\lambda) :=
> \sum_{\lambda_n \leq \lambda} P_n, \quad \lambda \in \mathbb{R},      
> (4.1) $$ defines a resolution of the identity on $\mathcal{H}$.

(Book's proof): Since the projections $P_n$ are pairwise orthogonal, $E(\lambda)$ is indeed a projection.
Let $x \in \mathcal{H}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $\sum_k P_k = I$ and hence $\sum_k \|P_k x\|^2 = \|x\|^2 < \infty$, there exists $k(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\sum_{k \geq k(\varepsilon)} \|P_k x\|^2 < \varepsilon^2.    (4.2)
$$
We show that axioms (i)–(iii) are fulfilled. Axiom (i) is obvious.
(ii): Let $\lambda_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. We choose $\lambda > \lambda_0$ such that the numbers $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_{k(\varepsilon)}$ are not in the left-open interval $(\lambda_0, \lambda]$. By (4.1) and (4.2) we then have
$$
\|E(\lambda)x - E(\lambda_0)x\|^2 = \sum_{\lambda_0 < \lambda_n \leq \lambda} \|P_n x\|^2 < \varepsilon^2.
$$
This in turn implies that axiom (ii) is satisfied.
My question: I don't understand how the author managed to prove axiom (ii). I mean, I understood what he did to obtain
$$ \|E(\lambda)x - E(\lambda_0)x\|^2 \leq \sum_{\lambda_0 < \lambda_n \leq \lambda} \|P_n x\|^2. $$
I mean, why is this sum less than $\epsilon$? He probably used equation (4.2), but that is the tail of this sum, which is different from the equation we obtained, where the sum runs between $(\lambda_0, \lambda]$.

The sum runs between $(\lambda_0, \lambda]$, but for $\lambda$ such that $\lambda_n \in (\lambda_0, \lambda] \Rightarrow n \geq k(\varepsilon)$, so that: $$\sum_{\lambda_0 < \lambda_n \leq \lambda} \|P_n x\|^2 \leq \sum_{n \geq k(\varepsilon)} \|P_n x\|^2 < \varepsilon^2$$
